# How to solve plane is not display correct if two plane is too close in three.js

Tags: three.js

How to solve plane is not display correct if two plane is too close in three.js?
http://archive.acroidea.com/images/plane2.jpg 
my plane is too close to the floor seems it not work correct, I'm a newer to study 3d, is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the planes further apart.

If you don't want to do that, you can try moving the camera `near` plane further away from the camera.

Alternatively, you can try moving the `far` plane closer to the camera.

Due to nonlinear effects, most of depth buffer precision is close to the `near` plane.